# How to turn comma delimited text file into a multidimensional array (formatted with radio buttons)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My text file contains:

*What is a dog?, A pet, A human, A house, A train*

I want to use that data to make a multidimensional array and use that array to post the question in quiz format.

For example:

*What is a dog?

[radio button] a.) A pet

[radio button] b.) A human

etc, etc*

So far, I coded...

```
<?php

$file = fopen ("data.txt","r");

$i=0;
while (feof($file)==false)
    {
    $line = fgets($file);   
    $array[$i]=$line;
    $i=$i + 1;
    }

fclose($file);

session_start();
$_SESSION["questions_array"]=$array;

?>
```

And to echo out the array...

```
<?php

session_start();
$array=$_SESSION["questions_array"];

for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
    {
    echo $array[$i]."<br>";
    }

?>
```

My problem with this is that it echoes out as:

*What is a dog?, A pet, A human, A house, A train*

instead of the quiz format I want. I am not sure how to echo out the array to the format I want. I've looked everywhere but received no solution. Please help me!

Specifics (just to be very clear):

I want to turn this text file:

*What is a dog?, A pet, A human, A house, A train*

into a multidimensional array and echo it out like this:

*What is a dog?

[radio button] a.) A pet

[radio button] b.) A human

etc, etc*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv)? :)

**Example:**

```
$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

$array = array();
while ($line = fgetcsv($file)) {
   $array[] = $line;
}
```

**Some improvements:**

This:

```
$array[$i]=$line;
$i=$i + 1;
```

...is useless. It could be:

```
$array[$i] = $line;
$i++;
```

...or better:

```
$array[$i++] = $line;
```

...or even better (as in my example):

```
$array[] = $line;
```

The use of `feof` here is also redundant. `fread`, `fgets` and `fgetcsv` already return `false` if EOF is reached.

**The output:**

Here's a code example to output it back as HTML:

```
foreach ($array as $q => $data) {
    echo '<p>'.array_shift($data).'</p>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $a => $answer) {
        echo '<li>'.
             '  <input type="radio" name="question-'.$q.'" id="question-'.$q.'"'.
             '         value="'.$a.'"/>'.
             '  <label for="question-'.$q.'">'.$answer.'</label>'.
             '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Ah, I haven't heard about fgetcsv but I'll surely look into that! Thank you very much! =]

Comment: @user1344705: Make sure to accept the answer if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can explode the line ( http://php.net/explode ) and use e.g. array element 0 of the inner array for the question, the following are used for answers.

```
$line = explode(',', $line);
$array[$i]=$line;
```

later on:

> echo $array[$i][0] . ' br>';
>
> $answers = count($array[$i]);
>
> for($j = 1; $j < $answers; $j++) {
>
> ```
> echo $array[$i][$j] . '<br>';
> ```
>
> }

Comment: The danger in this is the dreaded "comma in the question or one of the answers" problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've tried exploding the line but all I get is a loop of echoed 'array's. (i.e array <br> array...)

Comment: @user1344705 seen the inner "for" that returns answer by answer per question?

Comment: @hajo ah yes thank you I've forgotten about nested loops. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid modeling loops like this: `for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)` See http://www.phpbench.com for reasons why.

But let's take a closer look at your specific needs:

```
foreach($array as $source){
   $data = explode(",", $source);
   // Now $data[0] is the question, [1] is answer 1, etc.. etc..

   echo "{$data[0]} <br> 
           <input type='radio' name='question' value='1'>{$data[1]} <br>
           <input type='radio' name='question' value='2'>{$data[2]} <br>
           <input type='radio' name='question' value='3'>{$data[3]} <br>
           <input type='radio' name='question' value='4'>{$data[4]} <br>";
}
```

That should put you on the right path.

Comment: use `print_r($data);` to view your array design. But Dutchie432 makes a good point, commas in your "question" will cause some irregularities.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now get the logic behind this, but I'm getting the 'explode() expects parameter 2 to be string' error. I will try to fix that then.

Comment: Yeah, you can use something like what I've referenced above. Obviously the name needs to be unique to each question, and you need to make sure that your array design is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you'll want to build an array of arrays (thats what a multidimensional array is, afterall).

```
$quizItems=array();
$file = fopen ("data.txt","r");
while (feof($file)==false){
    $line = fgets($file);   

    //This code assumes no commas in the question or answers.
    $answers = explode(',', $line);

    //pull the question into a variable
    $question = $answers[0];

    //remove the question from the list of answers
    array_shift ($answers);

    //add the array to your result array
    $quizItems[]=array('question'=>$question, 'answers'=>$answers );
}
fclose($file);

var_dump($quizItems);
```

Here it is in action: http://codepad.org/lwOa7LNI

My code doesn't loop, I've just copied the code twice for illustration.

**Result**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["question"]=>
    string(14) "What is a dog?"
    ["answers"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) " A pet"
      [1]=>
      string(8) " A human"
      [2]=>
      string(8) " A house"
      [3]=>
      string(8) " A train"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["question"]=>
    string(14) "What is a car?"
    ["answers"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) " A vehicle"
      [1]=>
      string(7) " A tool"
      [2]=>
      string(9) " A number"
      [3]=>
      string(9) " A person"
    }
  }
}
```

**basic usage**

http://codepad.org/4Zhr9Wje

```
foreach ($quizItems as $quizItem){
    echo '<b>'.$quizItem['question'].'</b><br />'.
         implode('<br />', $quizItem['answers']);
}
```

**output**

> ```
> What is a dog?
>  A pet
>  A human
>  A house
>  A train
>
>
> What is a car?
>  A vehicle
>  A tool
>  A number
>  A person
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work if you have ',' in a question. This works only if your answers don't have question marks.

```
$question = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '?'));
str_replace($question, '', $line);
$answers = explode(',', $line);
$array[$i] = $question;
foreach($answers as $answer)
{
  $array[$i][] = $answer;
}
```